# Looping over Joined query

Tags: php, loops

I've got a query which outputs the following data:

```
Treatment ID --------- Treatment_Name ---------- Customer_type
1                      Treatment 1               Ladies
1                      Treatment 1               Mens
3                      Treatment 2               Ladies
4                      Treatment 3               Mens
```

I need to loop over this and output a similar structure to this:

```
<div class="mens ladies"> <!-- these are read from the customer_type column -->
    <h4>Treatment 1</h4> <!-- this is read from the treatment_name column -->
</div>
```

So basically grouping by the Treatment name (or ID) and then outputting all of the customers related to this treatment.

Coming from a ColdFusion background I assumed this would be easy with a Query of Queries etc. however I've struggled with coming up with a PHP solution.

I've tried to do a while loop and only show data if the treatment_name has changed which seems to work fine but I'm not sure how to display the customer_types related to this.

Any ideas? Thanks.

**Edit**
Here is a copy of the query returned from the db using a mysqli_fetch_all:

```
array (size=22)
  0 => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => string 'Mens' (length=4)
      1 => string '1' (length=1)
      2 => string 'treatment 1' (length=11)
  1 => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => string 'Ladies' (length=6)
      1 => string '1' (length=1)
      2 => string 'treatment 1' (length=11)
  2 => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => string 'Kids' (length=4)
      1 => string '2' (length=1)
      2 => string 'treatment 2' (length=11)
  3 => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => string 'Ladies' (length=6)
      1 => string '2' (length=1)
      2 => string 'treatment 2' (length=11)
  4 => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => string 'Mens' (length=4)
      1 => string '2' (length=1)
      2 => string 'treatment 2' (length=11)
  5 => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => string 'Mens' (length=4)
      1 => string '3' (length=1)
      2 => string 'treatment 3' (length=11)
  6 => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => string 'Kids' (length=4)
      1 => string '3' (length=1)
      2 => string 'treatment 3' (length=11)
  7 => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => string 'Ladies' (length=6)
      1 => string '3' (length=1)
      2 => string 'treatment 3' (length=11)
  8 => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => string 'Ladies' (length=6)
      1 => string '4' (length=1)
      2 => string 'treatment 4' (length=11)
```

It continues in the same format...

Comment: Could you paste the output of your query with print_r($query) i think i got the answer but i'm not sure of thath

Comment: Will there always be just 2 `Customer_type` and will they always be `Ladies`/`Mens`?

Comment: @xsami thanks, I've added a formatted version of the query from a mysqli_fetch_all(). Let me know if you need anything else.

Comment: @Sean thanks, there can be 1,2 or 3 Customer_types per treatment and they will be mens, ladies or kids or any combination of the three (with no duplicates) Ideally I would like to keep this dynamic so I can add more in future if required but it isn't an absolute must

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this answers your question:

```
<?php
    $link = mysqli_connect("hostname","username","password","database","port") or die("Error " . mysqli_error($link)); 
    $query = "SELECT treatment_name,Customer_type from Treatments" or die("Error at.." . mysqli_error($link)); 
    $result = $link->query($query); 

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $data[] = $row;
    }
//I have used this sample array: Try and make your result set this way
    $data = array(
                array('treatment_name'=>'Treatment1','Customer_type'=>'Mens'),  
                array('treatment_name'=>'Treatment1','Customer_type'=>'Ladies'),   
                array('treatment_name'=>'Treatment2','Customer_type'=>'Mens')
            );
    foreach ($data as $key => &$value) {
        $temp[$value['treatment_name']][$key] = $value['Customer_type'];
    }

    //echo "<pre>";
    //print_r($data);
    //print_r($temp);
    //die;

    foreach($temp as $key => $value){
        echo "<div class = \"";
        foreach($value as $key2 => $value2)
            echo " ". $value2. " ";
        echo "\"><h4>".$key."</h4></div></br>";
    }              
?>
//Output
<div class = " Mens  Ladies "><h4>Treatment1</h4></div></br><div class = " Mens "><h4>Treatment2</h4></div></br>
```

You can use the commented lines for checking the data and adjusting accordingly.
By the way, this code directly prints the output as html, so your browser will render it. Right click the page and view source  if you want the content!

Comment: This will create a `div` for every row returned. I believe the OP wants to combine the rows that are treatments for both. So using the sample data, there would be 3 divs, not 4.

Comment: Thanks for the answer MRazz however this returns a div per every row in the query which means there are multiple of each treatment. I would like each treatment_name to only appear once and have a class which has all of the customer_type values for all rows with the value of the same treatment name, ie. `<div class="ladies mens">Treatment 1</div>`